# Entity Framework Eager Loading Filter

Tags: entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a simple query I want to do like this:

1) `Products` have `ChildProducts` which have `PriceTiers`
2) I want to get all the `Products` that have a `Category` with a `ID` of 1 and `Display` = true.
3) I want to then include all the `ChildProducts` that have `Display` = true.
4) And then include the `PriceTiers` that have `IsActive` = true.

From what I have read, EF does not support Eager Loading with filters, so the following will not work:

```
ProductRepository.Query.IncludeCollection(Function(x) x.ChildProducts.Where(Function(y) y.Display).Select(Function(z) z.PriceTiers.Where(Function(q) q.IsActive))).Where(Function(x) x.Categories.Any(Function(y) y.ID = ID)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you start multiple questions for the same issue? Moreover why are you doing it again and again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start from the bottom up, meaning, apply filter on the `PriceTier` object and its parents, and include its parents (C# sorry, but hopefully you get the point):

```
repository.PriceTiers
  .Include("ChildProduct.Product") // eager load parents
  .Where(priceTier => 
    priceTier.IsActive &&
    priceTier.ChildProduct.Display &&
    priceTier.ChildProduct.Product.ID == 1 &&
    priceTier.ChildProduct.Product.Display)
  .AsEnumerable() // execute SQL statement
  .Select(priceTier => 
    priceTier.ChildProduct.Product) // return products rather than price tiers
```

(Note: `priceTier =>` in C# is the same as `Function(priceTier)` in VB.NET)

`MergeOption` should ideally be set to something **other** than `NoTracking` when executing the query. Otherwise, EF will not ensure that an object that appears multiple times in the result set of the query is only materialized once, such as a `Product` or `ChildProduct`:

**Unwanted results:**
PriceTier 1 and 2 have the same parents, but the parents have been materialized multiple times - once for each PriceTier.

- Product 1

  - ChildProduct 1

    - PriceTier 1
- Product 1

  - ChildProduct 1

    - PriceTier 2

**Ideal results:**
Set `MergeOption` to anything other than `NoTracking` to get these results:

- Product 1

  - ChildProduct 1

    - PriceTier 1
    - PriceTier 2

Comment: starting from the bottom up would have a side effect that if parents exist that dont have any children that match the filters those parents wont be in the result set. you could use a left join to achive your filtering

Comment: Over 5 years later this is still an issue with EF and your answer is still the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution that will give your 'rows' to match your request by using left joins instead of eager loading, and including parent rows where no child rows exist for the filters

```
var query = from product in Products
                join child_ in ChildProducts on product equals child_.Product into child_join
                from child in child_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join tier_ in PriceTiers on child equals tier_.ChildProduct into tier_join
                from tier in tier_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where product.Display && product.Category.ID == 1
                where child == null || child.Display
                where tier == null || tier.IsActive
                select new {product, child, tier};
```